# Is it safe to pass sensitive data to NextJs pages as server side props?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

I'm building a payment form with Stripe. The docs shows that if I want to use the `PaymentElement` then I need to have the client secret accessible on the front end. I know that exposing env vars to the front end with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` is the only option I see is to pass the client secret as a server side prop. I'm wondering though, is it safe? I know it will not appear as a prop in html but is it not possible to somehow dig it out of the browsers memory?

Comment: Isn't the client secret in Stripe called "publishable secret", with the obvious implication that it's okay to be published..?

Comment: Seems like I've confused it with the secret key (which should not be published). Their doc is not that clear about it though 

Comment: Yeah – you use the secret key when talking to Stripe in your backend code (if any), but for any client widgets, you use the publishable key.

Comment: Actually I confused it with the client secret you get when creating a payment intent. If I understand it correctly now, I'm supposed to create it before or when (ss or ajax) accessing a page